# Kafka-Streams Example With Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am new to Apache Kafka, I have created a Simple Spring boot Producer and Consumer Project, which can Produce and Consume messages properly, But now I want to work with Kafka Streams But facing difficulty to find a Simple POC for Kafka-Streams with Spring Boot, Could someone please share some simple and easy to understand projects with me, it would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Check this [Link](https://spring.io/blog/2018/04/19/kafka-streams-and-spring-cloud-stream) official documentation

Comment: @DjamelKr sir, Can you share any other example but official document. ?

Comment: If you are after some actual examples of how streams are created here is a good blog post example: https://tech4gods.com/kafka-streams-operations-with-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer below links for Kafka Stream processing with Spring

https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/02/stream-processing-with-spring-cloud-stream-and-apache-kafka-streams-part-1-programming-model

https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-2-apache-kafka-spring-cloud-stream/